# Do I lose the benefit of the Spores druid's Symbiotic Entity feature if I gain Temporary Hit Points from a different source?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, temporary-hit-points

The [Circle of Spores druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleofSpores)'s 2nd-level ability Symbiotic Entity reads as follows:

> As an action, you can expend a use of your Wild Shape feature to
> awaken those spores, rather than transforming into a beast form, and
> you gain 4 temporary hit points for each level you have in this class.
> While this feature is active, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - When you deal your Halo of Spores damage, roll the damage die a second
>   time and add it to the total.
> - Your melee weapon attacks deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to
>   any target they hit.
>
> These benefits last for 10 minutes, until you lose all these
> temporary hit points, or until you use your Wild Shape again.

I am just joining a party with a Twilight Cleric, who has the ability Channel Divinity: Twilight Sanctuary, which grants temporary hit points equal to 1d6+level.

If the Cleric uses their Channel Divinity: Twilight Sanctuary, and chooses to give my character the temporary hit points, then if my character were in Symbiotic Entity, would I lose Symbiotic Entity because of the phrasing:

> Until you lose all **these** temporary hit points

To clarify: Does accepting new Temporary Hit Points count as ***losing*** the original instance of Temporary Hit Points?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### You can keep Symbiotic Entity or get new temp HP, but not both

The [rules for temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) explain what happens when you gain new temp hp when you already have some:

> If you have temporary hit points and receive more of them, you decide whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones.

If the Cleric uses Twilight Sanctuary, your Druid chooses whether to keep the temporary hit points from their own Symbiotic Entity feature, and retain the other benefits, or accept the new temporary hit points and lose the benefits of Symbiotic Entity.

Answer (score 13):

#### If you took the temporary hit points, you would lose your Symbiotic Entity – but you can choose not to take them

[Temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) are specific to the source you got them from, but if you have two sources available you can choose which ones you keep:

> Healing can't restore temporary hit points, and **they can't be added
> together. If you have temporary hit points and receive more of them,
> you decide whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones.
> For example, if a spell grants you 12 temporary hit points when you
> already have 10, you can have 12 or 10, not 22.**
>
> [...]
>
> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration,
> they last until they're depleted or you finish a long rest.

So the Twilight Cleric may target you, but you do not need to accept the new source of temporary hit points. It does not result in automatically losing Symbiotic Entity.